# How to set the size of ALV grid when using function modules?

Tags: gridview, abap, resizable, alv

Trying to have more than 1 alv grid on my screen, and trying to place them at specific locations.

I'm guessing that finding a way to specify position and size to my alv grid would fix both problems.

The i_screen_start(end)_column(row) - like parameters only create a dialog box for me, but that's not what i want.

The is_layout-min_linesize and -max_linesize also doesn't seem do to anything as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the function modules to create a ALV, this won't be possible, as those always display the ALV in "Fullscreen" mode.

To get the functionality you want, you have to create you own screen with a Custom Container (or several) and attach your ALV Grid(s) to this container with class CL_GUI_ALV_GRID.

To learn more abaout the different custom container options, you can start by checking the examples in transaction DWDM

Comment: I'd recommend using the ALV Object Model instead (CL_SALV_*). You won't get support for using CL_GUI_ALV_GRID directly.